# Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000 microphone doesn't capture audio

Tags: microphone, pulse-audio, logitech-webcam

I got a Logitech Quickcam Pro 9000, the cam itself is working as it honors the UVC spec.

This fancy WebCam has a integrated mic which worked some time before but now, it does no more. (Note: I use pulseaudio as it is a USB Mic and I am not really keen on the hassle of ALSA setup)

Things I check already are if it gets detected at all:

```
$ lsusb |grep Logi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:0809 Logitech, Inc. Webcam Pro 9000
```

is not muted in alsa-mixer, volume at 100; pavucontrol shows it too, but no input level bar!

[image]

On top of that, if I open the gnome3 (fallback mode) audio panel (from the desktop panel), and disabel/reenable it in the hardware tab, it works "for some time".

Any hints? Any ideas? I am really out options for now, and the fact it worked like 6 months ago (perfectly) makes it no better.

Comment: unfortunatly not - I am happy with Arch (almost prefectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution: Unknown.
State: Fixed.

I stopped using skype entirely and I also did a reset of all config files related to pulseaudio and upgraded flashplayer and upgraded gnome to 3.x. Some of these changes did the trick.

Comment: As of now this no more issue for me.